# Oracle Temporary table columns and data from another table's rows

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Much like these questions:
[MSSQL Create Temporary Table whose columns names are obtained from row values of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28220209/mssql-create-temporary-table-whose-columns-names-are-obtained-from-row-values-of)

[Create a table with column names derived from row values of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820082/create-a-table-with-column-names-derived-from-row-values-of-another-table)

I need to do the same thing with Oracle, but i also need to fill this new table with data from another table which is organized in a particular way. An Example:

Table Users

```
|id|name |
----------
|1 |admin|
|2 |user |
```

Table user_data_cols

```
|id|field_name|field_description|
---------------------------------
|1 |age       |Your age         |
|2 |children  |Your children    |
```

Table user_data_rows

```
|id|user_id|col_id|field_value|
-------------------------------
|1 |1      |1     |32         |
|2 |1      |2     |1          |
|3 |2      |1     |19         |
|4 |2      |2     |0          |
```

What i want is to create, using only sql, a table like this:

```
|user_id|age|children|
----------------------
|1      |32 |1       |
|2      |19 |0       |
```

Starting from the data in the other tables (which might change with time so i'll need to create a new table if a new field is added)
Is such a thing even possible? I feel this might be against a lot of good practices but it can't be helped...

Comment: What is the logic to get the resulting data?  Do you have a normal query just to get the data?  And what do you mean by *"create a temporary table"*?  Do you just mean some normal table but you will use temporarily?  Because if you have a SQL, you can just do: `create table temp_table_name as select...`

Comment: i have a query to get the data, but the data will be in "vertical" form, as in row1=>user, field_name, field_value, row2=>user, field_name, field_value. For example i'd have ["admin", "age", 32],["admin", "children", 1],["user", "age", 19],["user", "children", 0]. What i want is this data in tabular form, with "field_name" values as column names and "field_value" values as rows data using only SQL

Comment: You're talking about pivoting. You can easily find information about how to do that.  But be aware that to do pivoting, you'll have to know in advance which values of `field_name` you will want to transform into column names.

Comment: I know about pivoting and it's not what i'm looking for because as you said i need to know in advance the values used.

Comment: You need *"dynamic column pivoting"* (if such a term exists)?

Comment: Essentially, yes (i like new terms, if they become something concrete). Maybe it'd be possible with a stored procedure?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Dynamic pivot in oracle sql](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15491661/dynamic-pivot-in-oracle-sql)

Comment: About this requirement "using only sql", does this statement mean that you will not consider a pl/sql block as an answer?

Comment: "Maybe it'd be possible with a stored procedure?" - yes, definitely.  The issue I have with your original question is you restrict the answer to 'using only sql'.

Comment: My bad here, misused terms. I meant to say if it was possible to do that without involving external code. Now i'm checking your suggestions

Comment: the Dynamic pivoting described in the article https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/ did the trick, thanks! (it's in one of answers from the duplicate, though it's not the accepted answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For comparison purposes here is the answer from your link:

[Create a table with column names derived from row values of another table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15820082/create-a-table-with-column-names-derived-from-row-values-of-another-table)

```
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    'CREATE TABLE Table_2 (',
    GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT
      CONCAT(nameCol, ' VARCHAR(50)')
      SEPARATOR ','),
    ');')
FROM
  Table_1
INTO @sql;

PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Now let's do the same in Oracle 11g:

```
DECLARE
  stmt varchar2(8000);
BEGIN
  SELECT 'CREATE TABLE Table_2 ('||
  (SELECT 
      LISTAGG(nameCol, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY nameCol) "cols"
  FROM 
  (SELECT DISTINCT nameCol||' VARCHAR2(50)' nameCol FROM table_1) table_x)||
  ')'
INTO stmt
FROM DUAL;
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE stmt;
END;
/
```

You asked if you can do this using 'using only sql', my answer uses a PL/SQL block.

You can fill such a table with data, using a similar strategy.  As others have noted, you must know the columns at parse time, to get around that restriction, you can follow a strategy such as was done here:

[Dynamic Pivot](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238)

Comment: I ended using this https://technology.amis.nl/2006/05/24/dynamic-sql-pivoting-stealing-antons-thunder/ which has been suggested in a post of the discussion you linked